Graphviz executables not on systems PATH
I have installed graphviz by using pip3 install graphviz (VScode on MacOS). When i try to run my .py file i get the error message:

"graphviz.backend.execute.ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute PosixPath('dot'), make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH".

I have checked everywhere and tried using commands such as
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/graphviz". 

But nothing happens. I would rather not install homebrew and get graphviz through that as I have had problems with homebrew. Is there a way to get the executables to work? Thanks in advance!

Check the pypi page:

To render the generated DOT source code, you also need to install [Graphviz][https://www.graphviz.org/] (download page, archived versions, installation procedure for Windows).

The python package you installed does not contain the graphviz exectuable. You will need to install it separately, no way around it.

Hi! Thank you. Installed graphviz with macports, worked fine up until fetching fontconfig-2.15.0.tar.xz from http://atl.us.distfiles.macports.org/fontconfig when it gave this:
Error: Failed to fetch fontconfig: Could not resolve host: atl.us.distfiles.macports.org
Error:See /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_graphics_fontconfig/fontconfig/main.log for details.Error: Follow https://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets if you believe there is a bug.Error:Processing of port graphviz failed,I have no knowledge how to fix
